# Label keeps updating on top of each other

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a form in which when a user clicks a button a label will pop up that will start from 1 and each time the user clicks that buttons it will change 1 to 2, 2 to 3 and so on.

I have created a Action event in which the code which gets the label on display shows and had some code now the problem i am getting is when it changes to 2 or more it overwrites the previous number so they are on top of each other.

I have tried 
test.setText("");

but it doesn't work as it only reads the last line.

This is the code which is inside the button actionevent

```
clickbutton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()  {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)  {
                String Labelforstore = Integer.toString(chocolates.differenttypesofchocolate);
                Label test = new Label(differenttypesofchocolate);
                test.setText(differenttypesofchocolate); 
                gridPane.add(test, 4, 4);
            }         
}
```

I am expecting the label to show but when a user clicks the button it deletes the previous number and so on. Rather then overwriting.

Comment: You are creating a _new_ `Label` and adding it to the `GridPane`—this will not remove any current children. You specify this new `Label` should have a row index of 4 and a column index of 4. If there are any children with those same constraints they will be rendered "under" the new child; z-order is determined by the order of the children in the parent's child list, by default. You probably want to change the text of the `Label` that's already added to the `GridPane`, which means you'll need a reference to it.

Comment: i dont get it...

Comment: About which part?

Comment: because i tried changing the text by test.setText(""); but it doesnt work

Comment: But `test` is a _different instance_ than the one previously added to the `GridPane`. Each time your `EventHandler` is invoked, you create a new instance of `Label`, set its text, and add it to the `GridPane`.